# cdef extern from ... NOGIL

Tags: python, cython

There's one thing I don't fully understand about the "nogil" applied to a cdef extern like this:

```
cdef extern from "pthread.h" nogil:

    ctypedef struct pthread_mutex_t:
        pass

    cdef int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *, void *)
    cdef int pthread_mutex_destroy(pthread_mutex_t *)
```

It isn't clear to me about the effect of that nogil, and I cannot find anything in the Cython's documentation about it. My interpetation is that the functions declared inside have the nogil implicitly. Am I right? And what about the struct?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Cython docs](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#declaring-a-function-as-callable-without-the-gil) on binding with C code

> The nogil function annotation declares that it is safe to call the
>   function without the GIL.

In your example, this means that the functions `pthread_mutex_init` and `pthread_mutex_destroy` are allowed in a `with nogil` block. In the absence of an explicit `with nogil` block, the GIL remains in place: it necessary but not sufficient to declare the function as done in the example.

Plain C variables can be used in the nogil blocks but you are responsible for the thread-safety.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thank you!