# How can I release the GIL before calling an embedded C function?

Tags: python, cython, gil

I have the following Cython code:

```
cdef public int CythonfunC():
    with nogil:
        embeddedCFunction()

cdef extern from *:
r"""
#include <wchar.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include "cfunctions.h";
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int embeddedCFunction(){
    //do stuff that don't require GIL
    return 0;
}
PyObject *OtherFunctions(){

    return PyObjectX;
}
"""
int embeddedCFunction()
```

The above code throws the following error: `Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil`. As suggested by some answers, I tried things such as `with nogil except:`, but I was not successful.

How do I release the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) before calling `embeddedCFunction`?

Comment: Potentially related: [cdef extern from ... NOGIL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49162218/11082165)

Comment: @Brian61354270, can I make specific functions with nogil? I've some PyObject * functions in my embeded C functions list.

Comment: `int embeddedCFunction() nogil`

Comment: Why is this up-voted? Post a [mre].

Comment: @relent95 it looks pretty close to a MRE to me (except for a small indentation error). You're welcome to vote how you like of course, but this is close enough that someone familiar with Cython will be able to answer it.

Comment: @DavidW, never close to a MRE. It contains unrelated code including an unknown header 'cfunctions.h'. It does not help future readers.

Comment: @relent95 but that doesn't actually prevent anyone reproducing the issue, which happens at the initial Cythonization stage rather than the subsequent C compilation stage or at runtime. It isn't perfect, but it's good enough to be answerable